# Getting libxls error with my filepath with read_xls function in R

Tags: r, url, xls

I have been trying to run the following codes below with the url: https://files.hawaii.gov/dbedt/economic/data_reports/DLIR/LFR_LAUS_LF.xls.

The url downloads an xls file. However using the `read_xls(temp, sheet = 1)` command in R is giving me an R. Any solutions? The file is supposed to be stored in the temp folder.

#### Scrape Employment Data from DBEDT

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))

#loads necessary packages to run codes
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(stringr)
library(taRifx)
library(lubridate)

#set url link for xls
# url <- "https://www.hirenethawaii.com/admin/gsipub/htmlarea/uploads/LFR_LAUS_LF.xls"
url <- "https://files.hawaii.gov/dbedt/economic/data_reports/DLIR/LFR_LAUS_LF.xls"

#create a temp file to load the xls and download the xls
temp <- tempfile(fileext = "xls")
download.file(url = url, destfile = temp)

#create a function to select only the columns we want
#grab date (col 2), labor force (col 3), employed persons (col 4), and unemployment rate (col 6) columns from state data
keep_cols <- function(data) {
  data <- data %>%
    select(2,3,4,6) %>%
    rename(date = 1, lf = 2, empl = 3, ur = 4)
  
  return(data)
}


#importing the xls sheets into our r environment
state_xls <- read_xls(temp, sheet = 1) %>% keep_cols() %>% mutate(geo = "HI")
```

The error is as follows:

```
 Error: 
  filepath: C:\Users\Jon Doe\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0iFXmt\file8eb8142165d0xls
  libxls error: Unable to open file
```

I am using a Windows laptop and the code was originally written in Macbookbbb

Comment: Strange, this works for me without any error.

Comment: @RonakShah I am using a PC btw. Any other modifications that can help it make work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem with Windows with `the download.file()`. So I added `mode="wb"` and it seemed to have worked. So basically this part of the code needed the change:

`download.file(url = url, destfile = temp, mode = "wb")`